# How can I know what are the heavier tables on my postgresql DB?

Tags: database, postgresql, size

I have a DB with a lot of data and I want to purge it! The thing is that IDK how to make the query.

Can somebody help me how can I know what are the heavier tables or unless the size of them on a Postgresql DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT table_name
       ,pg_relation_size(table_schema || '.' || table_name) AS size
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
ORDER BY size DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

to get 10 "heaviest" user-defined tables.

Comment: Sorry I'm a newby on this! Done!